# why does pandas diff return -1e-09 instead of 0?

Tags: python, pandas, precision

I'm reading a csv with these values (float64)

[image]

when I apply a diff(5) to this pandas I get the following:

[image]

The negative signs on -1e-09 are causing an issue later on.

when I tried to replicate the issue with

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[.2506,.2506,.2506,.25060001,.2506,.2506,.2506,.2506,0.24875,0.24875]})
df_diff = df.diff(5)
```

Which yields the same float64 dtype but the difference is 0.
What on earth is going?

Comment: What does your actual CSV data input look like? The display of `.2506` is almost certainly a rounded representation.

Comment: I can confirm that 0.2506 in the csv is 0.2506 with no rounding. I mean the 4th row is the one with all the extra decimals

Comment: Can you share the actual data for that column? Perhaps use `csv.reader()` on the file, opened as text. You can select the right column with `[row[columnindex] for i, row in csv.reader(open_file) if i < 9]` then show what that echoes as.

Comment: Also, try `with pd.option_context('precision', 20): print(df.head())`, this will show you up to 20 decimal digits rather than the default 6.

Answer (score 0):

The values in the first 3 rows are *not exactly `.2506`*. Pandas is just showing you a rounded representation.

You can do the same in numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.linspace(.2506, .25060001, 4)
>>> a
array([0.2506    , 0.2506    , 0.25060001, 0.25060001])
>>> a[0] - a[1]
-3.333333331578814e-09
```

The first two values *look* the same yet they still differ by a very small amount.

In the above numpy array representation, at least the 3rd and 4th value representations differ from the first two, but using the default display settings, putting these into a dataframe and echoing it, the resulting output doesn't show even that:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame({'foo': a})
      foo
0  0.2506
1  0.2506
2  0.2506
3  0.2506
```

You can increase the number of decimals shown by picking a higher `display.precision` value, see [*Options and settings*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html); the default for `display.precision` is 6. Easiest is to increase it temporarily with [`pandas.option_context()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': a})
>>> with pd.option_context("display.precision", 20):
...     print(df)
...
                      foo
0  0.25059999999999998943
1  0.25060000333333332101
2  0.25060000666666665259
3  0.25060000999999998417
```

If these small differences are causing issues, then just set any value below a threshold to zero:

```
df_diff = df.diff(5)
# we need to tolerate very small differences, any differences below 1e-8
# can be ignored.
toosmall = 1e-8
df_diff.A[df_diff.A.abs() <= -1e8] = 0
```